How to find which option or property is causing recompilation in CMake?
I have a large project, but due to bad CMake scripts, as long as I modify any of the CMakeLists.txt file, a full recompilation will be triggered. I want to find what is considered out-of-date by CMake and why, what should I do generally? Is it possible to get a verbose ouput of what happened after a modification?

If you edit the build script (in this case the CMakelists.txt file(s)) it doesn't seem strange to me that a full recompilation is done - in fact, I'd expect it, since changing that could change compiler or linker options and thus all files should be recompiled with the new options. If you just change a source (or header) file, then it's a different matter and I'd only expect that file, and whatever depends on it, to be recompiled.

@JesperJuhl It's natural that the modified target and those depend on it should be recompiled. But now, some unmodified dependees (which the modified target depends on) are also recompiled now. This is really time consuming, I want to avoid this.

Which generator are you using?

@AlanBirtles I'm using Ninja with Clang or MSVC

try ninja -d explain <target> https://groups.google.com/g/ninja-build/c/QfRD5MEZKR4
